# method repaint() not repainting, ball gravity animation

Tags: java, swing, repaint, gravity

The problem is that this ball after it is dragged and exited click, it is supposed to repaint according to the new y component given.   This is calculated from the gravity final and added to the velocity which is added to the existing y component in a loop.

I have debugged many times and I just cant hit it on the head.

Its supposed to..
move to where you drag it >>> when you let go it is supposed to fall until it hits the ground.

Thank you ahead of time.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DragBallPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
     private static final int BALL_DIAMETER = 40;
     private int screen_size_x = 300;
     private int screen_size_y = 300;
     private int ground_lvl = screen_size_y - 15;

     private int _ballX     = ground_lvl/2;
     private int _ballY     = ground_lvl - BALL_DIAMETER;
     private final double GRAVITY = -9.8;
     private double velocity;
     private static final double TERM_VEL = -100;

     private int _dragFromX = 0;
     private int _dragFromY = 0;

     private boolean _canDrag  = false;


     public DragBallPanel() throws InterruptedException
     {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screen_size_x, screen_size_y));
        setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        setForeground(Color.darkGray);

        this.addMouseListener(this); 
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
     {
        super.paintComponent(g);   // Required for background.
          g.setColor (Color.green);
          g.fillRect (0, 280, 400, 50 );
          g.setColor (Color.black);
        g.fillOval(_ballX, _ballY, BALL_DIAMETER, BALL_DIAMETER);

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();

        if (x >= _ballX && x <= (_ballX + BALL_DIAMETER)
                && y >= _ballY && y <= (_ballY + BALL_DIAMETER))\
          {
            _canDrag = true;
            _dragFromX = x - _ballX;
            _dragFromY = y - _ballY;
        } else
          {
            _canDrag = false;
        }
    }

    //===== mouseDragged ======
    /** Set x,y  to mouse position and repaint. */
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (_canDrag)
          {   // True only if button was pressed inside ball.
            //--- Ball pos from mouse and original click displacement
            _ballX = e.getX() - _dragFromX;
            _ballY = e.getY() - _dragFromY;

            //--- Don't move the ball off the screen sides
            _ballX = Math.max(_ballX, 0);
            _ballX = Math.min(_ballX, getWidth() - BALL_DIAMETER);

            //--- Don't move the ball off top or bottom
            _ballY = Math.max(_ballY, 0);
            _ballY = Math.min(_ballY, getHeight() - BALL_DIAMETER);

            this.repaint();
        }
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
          while(_ballY < ground_lvl)
          {
                 simulateGravity();
          }   
    }

     public void simulateGravity()
     {
         if(_canDrag)
         {
             try{
                 velocity = velocity + GRAVITY;

               if (velocity < TERM_VEL)
                 {
                    velocity = TERM_VEL;
                 }

                if (_ballY >= ground_lvl - BALL_DIAMETER)
                {
                   velocity = velocity/4; 
                } 
                _ballY += velocity;
                 Thread.sleep(400);
                 this.repaint();//**problem occurs here**

              }catch(InterruptedException ie)
              {
              }
         }
     }

    public void mouseMoved   (MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
}
```

main() class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;


public class DragDemo extends JApplet
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setTitle("Drag Demo");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          //window.add(new DragBallPanel());
        window.setContentPane(new DragBallPanel());
          window.setResizable(false);
        window.pack();
        window.show();
    }

    public DragDemo() throws InterruptedException
    {
        new DragBallPanel();
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: After adding a `main` and running that, I do not quite understand the problem.  I can drag the ball wherever I want, but if I move it to the left wall it sticks there and will not move any more.  Is that the intent?  If not, can you explain in other words what is supposed to happen?

Comment: It is a very small amount of code so I posted the entirety. I just edited it to just include the necessities. Thank you...

Comment: It is supposed to be dragged, then once you let go of the mouse it is supposed to fall to 'simulate gravity'.

Comment: *"a very small amount of code"* The 'problem' was not what it included, but what it **did not include!**  Please follow the link and read about the SSCCE and why they are a good idea.

Comment: **Tip**  If you add this code (a `main` method) to the bottom of the source, it becomes an SSCCE `public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    DragBallPanel dbp = new DragBallPanel();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, dbp);
   }
  });
 }`  Some might complain that 133 lines of code is not 'short', but I'll happily ignore them (199 lines is still short IMO).

Comment: I am terribly sorry I did not include the main() driver class. I added it below. Hope this is what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This **SSCCE** begins to show the problems in the code.

1. Compile the code.
2. Run it.
3. Drag the ball upwards.
4. Release the ball.
5. Remove the mouse from the drawing area, to see..
6. The ball fall ***upwards!***

You seem to have gotten the Y values upside down.  They start at top of screen, and go downwards.  Also, the code was blocking the EDT in an infinite loop.  To solve that, run the animation using a Swing `Timer`.

Please read the document on the SSCCE & ask if there is anything in it you do not understand.  I am well placed to explain.  :)

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DragBallPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{

    private static final int BALL_DIAMETER = 40; // Diameter of ball

    private int screen_size_x = 300;
    private int screen_size_y = 300;
    private int ground_lvl = screen_size_y - 15;

    private int _ballX     = ground_lvl/2;
    private int _ballY     = ground_lvl - BALL_DIAMETER;
    private final double GRAVITY = -9.8;
    private double velocity;
    private static final double TERM_VEL = 100;

    private int _dragFromX = 0;    // pressed this far inside ball's
    private int _dragFromY = 0;    // bounding box.

    /** true means mouse was pressed in ball and still in panel.*/
    private boolean _canDrag  = false;

    public DragBallPanel()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screen_size_x, screen_size_y));
        setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        setForeground(Color.darkGray);

        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
     {
        super.paintComponent(g);   // Required for background.
          g.setColor (Color.green);
          g.fillRect (0, 280, 400, 50 );
          g.setColor (Color.black);
        g.fillOval(_ballX, _ballY, BALL_DIAMETER, BALL_DIAMETER);

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        int x = e.getX();   // Save the x coord of the click
        int y = e.getY();   // Save the y coord of the click

        if (x >= _ballX && x <= (_ballX + BALL_DIAMETER)
                && y >= _ballY && y <= (_ballY + BALL_DIAMETER)) {
            _canDrag = true;
            _dragFromX = x - _ballX;  // how far from left
            _dragFromY = y - _ballY;  // how far from top
        } else {
            _canDrag = false;
        }
    }

    //========= mouseDragged =================
    /** Set x,y  to mouse position and repaint. */
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (_canDrag) {   // True only if button was pressed inside ball.
            //--- Ball pos from mouse and original click displacement
            _ballX = e.getX() - _dragFromX;
            _ballY = e.getY() - _dragFromY;

            //--- Don't move the ball off the screen sides
            _ballX = Math.max(_ballX, 0);
            _ballX = Math.min(_ballX, getWidth() - BALL_DIAMETER);

            //--- Don't move the ball off top or bottom
            _ballY = Math.max(_ballY, 0);
            _ballY = Math.min(_ballY, getHeight() - BALL_DIAMETER);

            this.repaint(); // Repaint because position changed.
        }
    }

    //====================================================== method mouseExited
    /** Turn off dragging if mouse exits panel. */
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
     {
         System.out.println("Exited: " + e);
        //_canDrag = false;
        runGravity();
        /*  while(_ballY < ground_lvl)
          {
             simulateGravity();
          }*/
    }

    Timer timer;
    ActionListener animate;

    public void runGravity() {
        if (animate==null) {
            animate = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    System.out.println("Ground: " + (_ballY-ground_lvl));
                    if (_ballY > ground_lvl) {
                        timer.stop();
                    } else {
                        simulateGravity();
                    }
                }
            };
            timer = new Timer(100,animate);
        }
        timer.start();
    }

     public void simulateGravity()
     {
         System.out.println("_canDrag: " + _canDrag);
         if(_canDrag)
         {

             velocity = velocity + GRAVITY;

           if (velocity > TERM_VEL)
             {
                velocity = TERM_VEL;
             }

            if (_ballY >= ground_lvl - BALL_DIAMETER)
            {
                //We have hit the "ground", so bounce back up. Reverse
                //the speed and divide by 4 to make it slower on bouncing.
                //Just change 4 to 2 or something to make it faster.
               velocity = velocity/4;
            }
            _ballY += velocity;
             //this.revalidate();
             this.repaint();
         }
    }

    public void mouseMoved   (MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                DragBallPanel dbp = new DragBallPanel();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, dbp);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `updateUI()` instead of `repaint()`.

If there is no effect remove the component and add it again.

Comment: Seems like (a poorly targeted &) random guess to me.  I've done plenty of animation and never had to call `updateUI()` as part of the process.  The 2nd suggestion is even worse. :(  Please delete this.  It is not an answer, and would make for a poor comment (presuming you had the rep. to post them).

Comment: Sorry, but i had exaclty that problem and it takes hours of time to find a solution.